# Web form security, changing field names

Tags: security, web

I've come across a website which changes it's field names every time it is refreshed, for example

```
<input value="" name="F337225905055ZJGKBU" type="text">
```

the second time I refreshed the webpage, it was

```
<input value="" name="F337225904870IUJ4RI" type="text">
```

The name of the field (i.e here it was the email field) kept changing its value. This is awesome because

1. Hard to send automated requests (Still possible, the bot can request a new page every time and can find the name of the field from the HTML and send automated requests, but this makes it harder for script kiddies.)

Besides this, what are the other benefits for changing the field names in the form every time it is generated?

I'm a mobile app developer and I'm new to the web arena. I'm looking into the web space currently and am learning jQuery and Rails.

What are the general web security risks should I anticipate from the very beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be used to protect against [Cross-Site Request Forgery attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) as the attacking site (probably) cannot guess the form fields’ names if they are associated to the user.

Comment: Thank you @Gumbo and What are the general web security risks should I anticipate from the very beginning?

Comment: don't forget simple bad coding - so many people focus on the "sexy" stuff & forget to write secure code:  http://www.codebyjeff.com/blog/2012/12/web-form-security-avoiding-common-mistakes